# c#, lambda expressions, where is the error?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have this method

```
    public static List<Contact> Load(string filename)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Data file could not be found", filename);

        }
        var contacts = 
            System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(filename).Root.Elements("Contact").Select
            (
                x => new Contact() { //errors out here, XXXXXX
                            FirstName = (string)x.Element("FirstName"),
                            LastName = (string)x.Element("LastName"),
                            Email = (string)x.Element("Email")
                         }
            );
        return contacts.ToList();// is this line correct?, it should return List...
    }
```

I have Contacts.xml with Contact elements in it.

```
<Contacts>
    <Contact>
        <FirstName>Mike</FirstName>
        <LastName>Phipps</LastName>
        <Email>mike@contoso.com</Email>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
        <FirstName>Holly</FirstName>
        <LastName>Holt</LastName>
        <Email>holly@contoso.com</Email>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
        <FirstName>Liz</FirstName>
        <LastName>Keyser</LastName>
    </Contact>
</Contacts>
```

I have a contact.cs with this code

```
public class Contact
{
    public Contact(string firstName, string lastName, string email)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Email = email;
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

on the line, where stamped with 'XXXXXX', how should i change the line to make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The constructor of your `Contact` class requires three arguments - `firstName`, `lastName` and `email` - but you're attempting to call the constructor with no arguments and then trying to set the properties using [object initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

To fix it you need to pass the three arguments into the constructor itself:

```
x => new Contact(
    (string)x.Element("FirstName"),
    (string)x.Element("LastName"),
    (string)x.Element("Email"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a public constructor in Contact.

```
public class Contact
{
    public Contact() {}

    public Contact(string firstName, string lastName, string email) {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Email = email;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Or just use the existing constructor.